# How to get Custom Build Tool property from VCConfiguration

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

Currently working on making an extension for Visual Studio C++ when dealing with files that are built using a custom build tool. For the life of me I can't find a way to drill down into the item that's currently selected's property panel.

Scenario:

- I have a `test.myfile` file in solution
- It is set to be built with a custom build tool

You can imagine it looks like this [image]

I currently have a command button in the item menu that executes as expected. I can get the selected items and from that grab the project items selected. I have the VCProjectItem and the VCConfiguration of the project tied to the file for the active configuration.

How can I get the "Command Line" property from the property page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get the "Command Line" property from the property page?

After l do a deep research, I found that we cannot use the property [VCCustomBuildTool.CommandLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.vccustombuildtool.commandline?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) to get the custom file's property **Command**. It can be used to get the **project's property**(right-click on the project) not the **specific file's property**(right-click on the file).

Or another way to think about it, since the file is created with the node like CustomBuild, so we can obtain them in xxxx.vcxproj file.

[image]

We can use [DTE interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte._dte?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) to get the current proj file of the current project and then read the child node **command** in the parent node  **custom build**.

For an example:

```
        using EnvDTE;
        using System.Xml;

        .........

        VCProject prj; 
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        DTE dTE = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE;
        prj = dTE.Solution.Projects.Item(1).Object;
        doc.Load(prj.ProjectFile);  //read the proj file for the current project
        XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
        XmlNodeList nodeList = root.GetElementsByTagName("CustomBuild"); //get the customBuild Node
        string str="";
        foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList) //search the child node 'command' in the parent node named custombuild
        {
            str += node["Command"].InnerText.ToString()+"-----";
        }
```

Please so not forget to reference the envdte.dll which exists in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies`.

Hope it could help you.

Comment: That certainly looks like that's the answer, I'm surprised I haven't stumbled upon it. Although, it's not clear how to get access to the VCCustomBuildTool structure for an item in the project. Do you know off hand how to arrive at one from a VCProjectItem or the DTE? Thanks!

Comment: Certainly not convenient as I would have hoped. I was able to get what I needed with a very similar approach that you've listed so I'll mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks!